# Android SDK component failed to install

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

while installing Android studio SDK in ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit using the wizard; I encountered this error

The following SDK components were not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21 and tools

It occurred during "Downloading Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, API 21, revision3"

Can someone please help me where the possible error is.

Comment: Try again?  I get a lot of temporary errors.

Comment: @GabeSechan I retried many times.

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me on Ubuntu 20.04 when I already installed the AS, but couldnt install packages in AVD Manager when I wanted to create a virtual device for the emulator, getting a very similar error. Maybe this will help in your case:

Delete the .downloadIntermediates/ directory from your SDK location /.../Android/Sdk/ (usually the path starts in your home folder).

> From what I understood, this folder contains logs for your downloads,
> and if something goes wrong, this can stop AS from
> resuming/downloading new things properly. Don't worry about deleting,
> this folder will recreate itself automatically and it doesnt affect
> the program

How to delete it via the console:

Open your terminal, go to your sdk folder, if it's a default location in home folder the command is as follows:

```
cd Android/Sdk
```

Then check if the folder ".downloadIntermediates/" exists. Run this command and look for it in the list:

```
ls -la
```

If it's there, then proceed with removing it:

```
rm -r .downloadIntermediates
```

Now you can run the "ls -la" again to see if it is removed successfully.

Launch Android Studio again. Now try installing all the packages you need, they should install with no errors. Hope this helps in your case! :) And in any case, if nothing else works, an uninstall and clean install can be a good idea.